# parametrize output of pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to parametrize the output of a pytest fixture. For example, let's say I have two fixtures:

```
# contents of test_param.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[1,2])
def fixture_1(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_2(fixture_1):
    for num in range(5): # the output here should be parametrized
        return '%d_%s' % (fixture_1, num) # but only returns first iteration 

def test_params(fixture_2):
    print (fixture_2)
    assert isinstance(fixture_2, str)
```

Then when I run the following:

```
py.test test_param.py
```

Only the first iteration from fixture 2 gets passed for each param in fixture 1. How can I parametrize the output of fixture_2 such that each iteration in the for loop gets passed to the test_params function?

Edit : Assume the second fixture cannot be parametrized in the same manner as the first because in the real problem the output of the second parameter is dependent on input from the first fixture.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `return` which returns from the fixture function.

Why not parametrize the second fixture just like you did the first?

```
# contents of test_param.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[1,2])
def fixture_1(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=list(range(5)))
def fixture_2(fixture_1, request):
    return '%d_%s' % (fixture_1, request.param)

def test_params(fixture_2):
    print (fixture_2)
    assert isinstance(fixture_2, str)
```

Comment: In this example it would work, but what if the output of the second depends on the input from the first? In the test I am working on, for example, the first fixture returns a directory and the second a subset of the files in the directory.

Comment: py.test currently does not support dependent parameterization